# Read the Adjacent cell value in Excel Sheet using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet and I want to give it a string input and have the java code look for the input in the excel sheet. And when it finds it, it prints the adjacent cell (the one on its right).

This code just gives me all the excel sheet values. But what I want is for it to give me a specific value.

This is my code:

```
package readfiles;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class LeerArchivosDeExcel {

    public LeerArchivosDeExcel(File fileName){
        List cellData = new ArrayList();
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
                XSSFRow hssfRow = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
                List cellTemp = new ArrayList();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()){
                    XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) iterator.next();
                    cellTemp.add(hssfCell);

                    }
                cellData.add(cellTemp);    
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obtener(cellData);
    }
    private void obtener(List cellDataList){
        for (int i = 0; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) {
            List cellTempList = (List) cellDataList.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < cellTempList.size(); j++) {
                XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) cellTempList.get(j);
                String stringCellValue = hssfCell.toString();
                System.out.print(stringCellValue+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File ("/Users/sushi/Documentos/BD2/Libro.xlsx");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (f.exists()){
            LeerArchivosDeExcel obj = new LeerArchivosDeExcel(f);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Iterating the values in the worksheet can be quite simple. Baeldung has a good article introducing Apache POI with Excel https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-excel.

Comment: I have a question to help me understand what you are asking...Suppose you are searching for value "foo" and find it in cell A1. B1 adjoins A1, but suppose it is empty. C1 contains value "bar". Do you want to return the empty value from B1 or the value "bar" from C1 in this case?

Comment: I want B1 value. I will fill column A1 and B1 with values, i want to put an input and that the java code search for that input in the excel sheet and it prints the adjacent value. If im searching for "foo" and find it in cell A14, i want the code to print B14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a method like this:

```
public String getAdjacentCellValue(Sheet sheet, String searchText) {
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (searchText.equals(formatter.formatCellValue(cell))) {
                // text matches the string cell value,
                // so find the adjacent cell
                Cell adjacentCell = row.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex() + 1);

                if (adjacentCell == null) {
                    // cell does not exist in excel model yet,
                    // so it is considered a blank cell by default
                    return "";
                } else {
                    // cell exists in excel model
                    // return the value
                    return formatter.formatCellValue(adjacentCell);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // search text not found
    return null;
}
```

Some notes are appropriate here:

1. You can iterate the worksheet this succinctly because the [`Sheet`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html) interface extends `Iterable<Row>` and the [`Row`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html) interface extends `Iterable<Cell>`.
2. Use [`DataFormatter`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to read a cell's string value because`cell.getStringCellValue()` will not work if the cell type is `NUMERIC`, for example.  Additional configuration will be necessary if the cell is a formula cell.
3. The method invocation `row.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex() + 1)` may return null. Internally, Excel assumes that all cells in a sheet are blank cells unless otherwise specified. It only stores cells that have been explicitly edited. If the cell has never been created POI returns `null`. This is not unusual for a typical worksheet.